# Remote Desktop Password isn't working anymore for external connections

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I've a Windows 2008 R2 Server.
If I connect via Remote Desktop with the internal IP (in the intranet) everything works fine,
but if try to connect via my external IP it always says that my password is wrong.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the NAT rules changed? Is that external IP address no longer directing traffic to the internal address you're expecting? Might be a little hard to tell if you're using network-level authentication, but if you disable that so you can see the server console while logging in, it should be easier to tell if you're connecting to the server that you expect.

Comment: yea thank you.. you were right.. someone at my work changed the port forwarding for the RDP ...

Answer (score 0):

What RDP client are you using? Are you appending your username with the domain or server name when logging on externally? If not, try that.

Comment: its the remote desktop connection contained in windows... yes i connect like that: domain\username .. everything was working fine.. i wasnt connected to the server for about one week.. after i tried.. it suddenly told me that my password is wrong.. i though something happend.. i used a linux tool to reset my password.. set a new one.. and figured out that it only works when i use the internal ip

Comment: Change you password from the windows system (ctrl+alt+del -> change password) and see if that resolves the issue